# Getting WebView version for a user?

Tags: android

In an android app, is the WebView version statically tied to the OS version? Is there such a thing as the WebView class getting updated on the side, independent of the OS version getting updated? I'm reading this page and it seems that this is the case:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

I'm trying to debug a problem and am not sure what version of WebView a particular user has. Is there a way to get the 'version' from WebView? It seems not:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Just to be clear, I'm not talking about the browser apps (which can obviously be updated independently) - I'm talking about the actual WebView class.

Thanks

Comment: I'd imagine this would only be updated as part of an OS update. But as to whether each OS version uses the same class version is another story.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, the WebView component bundled with each Android release is only updated through OS updates. With Android 4.4, the WebView was updated to incorporate technology from Chrome rather than WebKit itself and it seems a minor version update also updated the WebView component with new features.

It does appear however that there may be future support for dynamic updates of the WebView component from the [Chrome Developer Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview):

> Your apps inside a WebView are just as important and deserve a runtime that keeps users up to date. There are large engineering and logistical challenges. We're not quite there yet, but we're working on it.

In regards to you debugging that problem, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is a good resource to quickly check if certain features are available in WebView for a particular Android version. It might pay to look there to identify any functionality you have used that might be either missing support or have issues for the minimum Android version target you have defined for your application.